# Riak Nodes and Cluster Backup

Tags: riak

I have a riak node that has a lot of data on it but IS NOT part of a cluster, and I have a cluster with 2 nodes with no data on it. The command

```
backup riak@127.0.0.1 riak /dev/nodebackup.dat all
```

Does not seem to be working anymore, and the backup that was produced was corrupted. If I add this node to the cluster, will the data then be copied to the other 2 nodes in the cluster? Is there a way where I can force the data to be copied when adding the new node?

Answer (score 0):

The backup and restore functions of riak-admin have been deprecated (http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/tools/riak-admin/#backup) and are no longer supported.

The current recommendations for backing up clusters can be found here: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/backups/

If you add your node to the existing 2 node cluster your data will be redistributed around the now 3 node cluster.